# Copy and Paste Specific character into existing pose

Tags: animation

I have what might be a tough or easy question. My overall use for blender is to create multiple animations for different characters. Some of these animations will be the same, and I was wondering if theres a way that I can make a basic animation, then copy and paste the character's look (skin, mesh, whatever you want to call it) onto the base character. So then I can just do that with all the different characters.
The proportions will be the same between characters.

I just need a way to have the exact same animations for multiple characters without having to animate it myself many times over, because I wouldn't be able to make it exact.

Any questions about this, please just clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I think the best thing to do is to make a file of just the armature doing the animations. Select "Save as" and do a different name, then, at frame 0 have the armature in a neutral position (and have the animation start at frame 1) so you can copy the meshes into the file and rig the meshes for different characters onto the neutral position.
Just return to the original file and "save as" again for a new character.
Did this help?